# How to turn off ehcache for test purposes

Tags: java, ehcache

I have an implementation of ehcache which doesn't use any config from an xml but as shown below:

```
private Ehcache cache;

constructor {
  cache = CacheManager.getInstance().addCacheIfAbsent("nameOfCache");
  CacheConfiguration config = cache.getCacheConfiguration();
  config.eternal("false")
  config.setTimeToLiveSeconds(<someTime>);
}
```

Now, I have used guava cache before and I know that by setting the eviction time to `0` in a guava cache, it turns off the caching. But by reading the documentation about ehcache, I understand its not the same case. Is there any other way to turn the cache off?

Answer (score 16):

From [the Ehcache FAQ](http://ehcache.org/documentation/faq#is-there-a-simple-way-to-disable-ehcache-when-testing), you can set the `net.sf.ehcache.disabled` system property to inhibit Ehcache from adding elements to a cache.  Because no elements will be added to the cache, every cache request will result in a cache miss, providing the behavior you're looking for.

If you're launching the  JVM from the command line, you can set the property like this:

```
-Dnet.sf.ehcache.disabled=true
```

Comment: Here is new [link](https://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/configuration/configuration.html#:~:text=net.sf.ehcache.disabled) to the Ehcache FAQ

Answer (score 0):

No sure how to do this for Ehcache but we did something similar on my project. First, we wrote a facade pattern for cache (to allow for the use of either Ehcache or Guava cache behind it). Then I implemented an `OptionalCache` that takes a `Nullable` cache or cache builder as the constructor. If the cache is present the `OptionalCache` uses it, otherwise it does not (either using the `CacheLoader` to get the value or returning `null`). This allowed us to pass null for the cache / cache builder for testing.